# Print table data on click not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a table values and I saw a script here in StackOverflow, the problem is that it's not working here. I don't why, I think maybe I should replace this "event" parameter with something. What's wrong?

The `clico()` function does works, but the `myFun()` doesn't.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function clico(){
    alert("clico!!");
}

function myFun(e){ 
    alert(e.target.innerText); //current cell
    alert(e.target.parentNode.innerText); //Current row.
}​
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="tableID" border="5" onclick="myFun(event)">
  <tr>
     <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
     <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
     <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: That "invisible special character" thing solved the scripting problem, but now I get a "undefined" print instead of the table values... that is only with firefox. Internet explorer and chrome works perfectly! is it a problem with firefox or am I missing something in the settings here?

Comment: I want to retrieve the data contained in the clicked row. I've tried that, didnt work too.

Comment: i copied this code from another topic here in stackoverflow... but if it's completely incorrect, what do i have to do then to retrieve the data from the clicked row in the table? i want to use javascript.

Comment: @renatoff - Sorry somehow I forgot `target` always refer to the element clicked. Your code has an error because of the last character (after `}`) in your `<script>` tag, not because of `event` or `target`.

Comment: where exactly? i cant see. there is no character after }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you got this, but there are invisible special characters after the last `}` which causes an error. You can only view those special characters/bytes using an hexadecimal editor

[image]

In this screenshots, the special characters are shown as dots on the right part, like new lines, but as you can see, their values on the left are different. The three red ones are the bug.

To get rid of it, the best thing to do with your editor is to select around it, including a few lines/words, and then delete it and rewrite it manually.

Comment: dude... thats impossible.. hahaha! its working now.. but i get a "undefined" message instead of the table values....

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var rows = document.getElementById('tableID').rows;

    var handler = function(e) {
            alert(e.target.innerHTML); //Alerts the clicked cell's value
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].onclick = handler;
    } 
}
```